# w3c html checker on localhost

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there is a program out there that checks to see if I have a beginning an end tag for each html markup item. I use Dreamweaver cs3 and when something is wrong with the markup, a tag changes color but, its not always accurate. I was wondering if there is someway I can have the beginning and end tags put into a tree view rather than having to open and close each tag in tree view in Dreamweaver.

So something that is displayed like this:

```
+<div id="abc">
| some html
| some html
| some html
| some html
+</div>

+<div id="def">
| some html
| some html
| some html
| some html
+</div>
```

Comment: 9 errors and 1 warning for this page :D just tried the recommended W3C Validator FF plugin

Answer (score 5):

Try using Eclipse with the Aptana plugin, it's got pretty solid code-highlighting.

Somewhat irrelevantly, if you're doing W3C validation, use the FF web developer plugin and use ctrl+shift+a as a shortcut to validate local code.

Answer (score 2):

Well I dont know if this is what you want but I personally use this "HTML Validator" Firefox extension. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249

This validates your code for start and end tags and much more. It pretty much checks that it's valid according to W3C standards.

If what you want is HTML syntax highlighting NetBeans has a pretty good one and supports many server side programming languages.

Comment: problem is everytime i want to validate i have to upload the entire website. im doing this on localhost

Answer (score 2):

[HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)?

You can also [install](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html) W3C's validator on your system.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike mentioned Eclipse would be good to work on. Still i prefer "VI or VIM" Editor under linux. Indenting and formatting feature would be really useful.

If you would like to install the W3c Validator on your local machine then try installing [Xampp Package](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)(as it is bundles with Apache,Php,Mysql) then install [W3c validator](http://www.obsidianproject.co.uk/phpw3cvalidator). It will work in any operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for. Using the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) Extension for Firefox will show you a tree view of the current page.

If you are looking for a text editor with syntax highlighting, there is [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) for windows. For linux, gedit has syntax highlighting. Of course vim and emacs is available for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I use [HAML](http://haml.hamptoncatlin.com/) and now I will never have to close a tag again.  Also besides the Firefox extensions, you have the [SafariTidy](http://zappatic.net/safaritidy/) plugin for Safari which will check all your tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can find [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) is helpful for you. Or use online [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) from [w3c](http://w3.org).